# What is the possessive form of “Daniel's” if “Daniel’s” is the name of a company?

Tags: sentence-construction, possessives

If a company's name is Daniel's what is the correct possessive form?
Like in the sentence:

> I used to work at Daniel's {' / 's} Human Resources Department.

Comment: 1. It is not obligatory to use the possessive form of a company name; 'I work at Ford' is more standard than 'I work at Ford's' 2. Many native speakers might avoid an awkward double possessive by using an article: 'I work at the Daniel's HR Department', or just avoiding the second possessive altogether:  'I work at Daniel's HR Department', See here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/possessive-of-a-word-that-is-already-possessive

Comment: The London store **Harrods**, founded by Charles Harrod, has no apostrophe.

Comment: @Weather Vane - No, but the OP is asking about a name that *does* have an apostrophe. That is the whole point of the question.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica it was an example for the previous comment, which stated that it is not obligatory to use the possessive for a company name.

Answer (score 2):

When used as the name of a company, “Daniel's” has an implicit subject attached to the possessive Daniel - “Daniel's Stores”, “Daniel's Motor Repairs”, and the like. Maintaining the unspoken subject would mean “Daniel's Stores' HR Department” is expressed as “Daniel's HR Department”.

Practically all native speakers would not consider this and simply say “Daniel's HR Department” for simplicity's sake.

Comment: "Practically all native speakers would not consider this and simply say Daniel's HR Department for simplicity's sake." Maybe in informal speech, but in formal writing you should probably use the full name of the company.

Answer (score 0):

I think @jla's answer is solid, but there are a few comments and answers who are concerned with `correctness` so I offer an alternative. The construction presented in the OP is inherently quite informal, if correctness is your concern you need to restructure the sentence.

> I used to work in the Human Resources Department at Daniel's.

> I used to work in the Human Resources Department at Daniel's Autoparts.

> I used to work at Daniel's in the Human Resources Department.

> I used to work at Daniel's Autoparts in the Human Resources Department.

`Daniel's Human Resources Department` isn't the actual name of any subject, there is a department `Human Resources (Department)` at the company `Daniel's` but this is not nominally `Daniel's Human Resources Department` either internally or publicly.

In fact, this structure is effectively the full form contracted in the OP.

> I used to work at Daniel's <s>in the</s> Human Resources Department.

Answer (score -1):

**Daniel's' HR Department**, is grammatically correct in my opinion.

However I would go with the solution in a comment suggested by @Michael Harvey

'I work at the Daniel's HR Department'